# How to containerize apps?

Tags: permissions, virtualization, sandboxing

There are a lot of Android apps out there that request all sorts of permissions. They want access to your files, your contacts, etc. Many of them don't run properly and/or crash without these permissions.

Is there a way of installing and running these apps without exposing information? Can I "containerize" apps, where it is still granted permissions but runs in a sandbox/container where my personal information isn't visible?

The usual way for me to do this on a computer is to run the app in a virtual machine, but VMs are not available on Android. Alternatives?

Comment: First of all, all apps on android are sandboxed against each other so one app can't access data of other apps. However of you grant some permission to some app it's granted if not than it's not granted. What do you mean by "exposing information" ? This sounds like paranoia to me. Just one more thing if you allready  use android or anything else connected on internet forget about privacy. The safest way to hide personal info is not having it on device which have access to internet, or on a pc whic doesn't have a way to connect to internet or simply use paper.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје For example, many games ask for "Media/Photo/Files" and "Read Contacts" permissions and don't run unless they are given these permissions. I'd like to try these games without giving it access to this information. How do I do this?

Comment: Not possible to run game it must have access to storage how would it load all textures and other stuff, access contacts is needed if game is connected with google play or any other account. So don't be paranoid, and do not keep sensitive data on phone if you are so scared

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје that got nothing to do with paranoia, just with common sense. For some background, also see: [Dangers of ad modules in apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/169781/16575) And besides: if an app needs access to my contacts just because it's "connected with google play or any other account", the dev made a bad mistake (that permission is not needed for this, find some details in [Android 6+ and account permissions: where have they gone to?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/157350/16575)).

Comment: **Ana:** Is your device rooted, or would you consider rooting if that offered a solution? If not: There are VMs for Android which you can run on your PC to try things out.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје You are conflating paranoia with desire for security.

Comment: Maybe. My tought is that if you use someone's else not your own software there isn't security, so I don't bother with 'security'. Don't keep sensitive info on phone and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Izzy No. With this conversation, I'm going to venture a guess containerization is not possible with unrooted Android now.

Comment: @Ana there are possibilities (need to find that app again) – but I'm afraid you wouldn't like it: The "container manager" itself requires so many permissions I didn't dare taking a closer look. Though they somehow make sense, as it needs to manage those "in the name of the contained app" to be able to intercept.

Comment: @beeshyams I was a fool. I even wrote it was an app with so many permissions; so I just needed to sort my list by that (descending), and find it right on top (literally; 101 permissions required): [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl). The feature asked for here can be found in the second bullet-point of the app's description.

Comment: @Izzy: not sure if it is a case of jumping into fire from the frying pan : )

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје "if you use someone's else not your own software there isn't security, so I don't bother with 'security'." → So when you're living in a hotel room, you leave the door open and the money on the table? Ugh. I'd rather check whether my bags can be locked, and rent a safe. Which is, figuratively, what Ana asks for.

Comment: @beeshyams Exactly what I pointed out above ("I'm afraid you wouldn't like it"). Though *Parallel Space* has a pretty good rating: ~4.5 stars at ~1.5Mio (!) votes. Quite impressive. Still, I might try it on a VM to see its workings, but I doubt I'd let it on one of my "real devices" :)

Comment: @izzy: I don't give much credit to the app rating- likely to be more utility of app oriented rather than look into security angle. Anyway if you do study it on CM, be kind enough to share your findings. Thanks

Comment: @beeshyams I'm not studying it on **CM**. I wrote "I might try it on a **VM**". But that has a handicap, see my currently newest question: I can't get any recent version of Android running in Virtualbox on Linux. So the "I might" is plainly theoretically.

Comment: @izzy: pardon my typos please. Hope you do get your answers and in turn benefit lazy folks ( read *me*)

Comment: If I get that other issue solved, it will definitely benefit not only me, @beeshyams :) And right now, there's some light at the end of the tunnel (Firelord seems to have it running on Slackware). I just hope it's not the headlights of an oncoming train #D

Comment: Maybe this can help https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/closed-beta-test-incoming-companion-app-t3366295