# How to disable hidden trackers, in google play store applications

Tags: applications, root-access, privacy, xposed-framework, ads

So most applications, on google play have hidden trackers, analytics they don't tell you about. This site lets you search any app shows trackers. The article explains what i'm talking about.

Example: https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/reports/37324/

Article : https://theintercept.com/2017/11/24/...-android-apps/

Article : https://www.wired.com/story/android-users-to-avoid-malware-ditch-googles-app-store/

The second article explains Fdroid is partly a solution as those apps there don't have these trackers. One other not a full solution is uninstalling the app removes the tracker.

Certain apps on google play store either open source or proprietary don't include trackers as far as exodus-privacy.eu.org analysis is aware of, it's possible there's some there unaware of as they state.

Applications without trackers could later receive trackers through application updates. The other option is researching the extent of the specific trackers used in certain applications and what there been used for.

I want to know how it's possible to disable these trackers, analytics so there not active in the background "while" using these apps.

I saw XPrivacyLua xposed module can disable certain analytics.

Appreciate all advice.

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/202282/131553

Comment: Yeah i've seen that, you can be tracked regardless of a app displays ads, that's why there hidden trackers. Read this: https://theintercept.com/2017/11/24/staggering-variety-of-clandestine-trackers-found-in-popular-android-apps/

Comment: 1. XprivacyLua is the best I know of 2. [Izzy's repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid) warns you of the anti features to make an informed decision.

Comment: I was wrong about F Droid and deleted those comments

Comment: XPrivacyLua is not based on the hosts file. It disables the corresponding activities in the apps having them. But to do so, it must know them; I'm not sure of the coverage, though it certainly covers the major candidates.

Comment: Yeah it's apps on google play with trackers hidden in them, the permission system of android and XprivacyLua won't do anything to stop them. Not to mention there kept secret from anyone installing apps, simply having an app installed means it's happening, i just no from reading XprivacyLua forum, it can block some Analytics but not through app permission allow, deny camera access example i'm sure it doesn't cover everything either. So it's either avoid all google play store apps or use fdroid only not entirely feasible, install the extention Exodify exodify.org browse google play website will

Comment: show you all the trackers in apps using a web browser you would use Ublock Origin or Disconnect extentions ect pretty hard when there embedded inside the apps themself.

Answer (score 2):

***Root access needed***

Both of these apps are likely using built in `pm disable` [command in Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#pm), which lets you to disable app's services, activities, receivers and providers (all of these can be done from command line too). Significant part of ads and tracking stuff can be disabled this way. Of course developer can hide whatever they want, so it won't be accessible through `pm disable`. Afaik it can disable only things mentioned in app's manifest. Also apps can reenable all of these back (I think I noticed such behavior only in system apps)

**1)** **MyAndroidTools Pro**  (which I use)
It has free and paid versions. Author was banned in Play Store, but you can still buy outdated version (1.5.1 instead of 1.6.0) on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/%E7%8E%8B%E7%90%A6-MyAndroidTools-Pro/dp/B00REQGZ3O) or find apk somewhere else..
App has convenient option to display component info after new app is installed/updated.
Developer made [Xposed module](https://repo.xposed.info/module/cn.wq.myandroidtoolsxposed) to prevent apps reenabling components, but it was abandoned long time ago, so you'll have to check if it works for you.

<sub>(Click on image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

**2)** [**Lucky Patcher**](https://www.luckypatchers.com/)
Free app, also not in Play Store. Downside: developer started embedding ads (removed in current version) and analytics recently, which require excessive permissions.
To disable components:
Long tap on app in the list -> Change The App's Components -> Disable components 'pm disable' method (may be enabled by the application) -> Select components -> Apply

Comment: That module hasn't been updated in last two years and developer is inactive on XDA thread

Comment: @beeshyams yep, I don't even know if it works. Just added for completeness.

Comment: @janot bro, if you haven't used it, know it hasnt been updated, and don't even know if it works, why bother plugging it?  And put those disclaimers in the answer.