# How to stop installed apps accessing the unique hardware identifiers for the device?

Tags: permissions, privacy, ads, profiles

I understand that Unique hardware IDs such SSAID, IMEI, serial number, and Advertising ID are accessible by installed applications on Android phones and that enterprises and certain governments make use of these IDs (via the installed apps) for purposes of location tracking, profile building, data collection, targeted advertising, and sometimes surveillance/spying. Aside from obvious privacy and freedom issues with the above, I understand that the data generated from this is also potentially inaccurate where a phone changes owner or in the case of any phone which is running more than one profile/account, eg. in a family where more than one person uses the same phone. https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/android-device-identifiers/31755/

**How can applications installed on android devices be prevented accessing all these unique hardware IDs (SSAID, IMEI, serial number, Advertising ID, etc.)?**  I see nothing specific regarding them in the full list of modifiable permissions for apps, which I am currently looking at using using 3C Toolbox.

Note:
i) I don't care if this means my phone is harder to trace/block if it gets stolen.
ii) IMEI modification/spoofing is not the topic of this question.

Comment: Root your Phone and use [XPrivacyLua](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=XPrivacyLua) // It works for most part on Android 11 too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an adblocker defeat the tracking part of the ad module, or just the display of ads?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202282/does-an-adblocker-defeat-the-tracking-part-of-the-ad-module-or-just-the-display)//Question is not duplicate but the answers cover what you ate looking for IMO

Comment: It partly answers it I'd say. It doesn't go into full details about how to block app access to all the phone's identifiers, which would presumably end up being pretty much a course in coding for Android, but it does mention most of them, and suggests software that is the best option for it currently, in their opinion.